# Checking a checkbox based on a textbox value

Tags: c#

The code I have here is supposed to load three separate values from three lines in a .txt file. This works fine so far. LOAD1 works well, and gets converted to an integer and then put back into the program as expected.The trouble is LOAD2.

What I'm trying to do: I want this bit of code to check whether the text "counter clockwise" is the text in LOAD2. If it is, I want it to automatically check a checkbox (RotDir, which is also available for manual input in the main program). The only other available text that can be in that textbox is "Clockwise", which should leave RotDir unchecked. So ticking a checkbox by using input from a textbox, is this possible?

I figured, this can be solved with a basic true/false kind of statement, since it is only two values. However, this does not seem to work. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Gebruik\\Desktop\\Settings.txt");
string[] lines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
LOAD1.Text = lines[3];
LOAD2.Text = lines[7];
LOAD3.Text = lines[10];

int A = Int32.Parse(LOAD1.Text);
ServoSpd.Value = A;
label1.Text = LOAD1.Text;

if (LOAD2.Text == "Counter Clockwise")
{
    ServoDir.Checked = true;
}
else
{
    ServoDir.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean this? `Counter Clockwise` is it a text literally or you  need a reverse text.

Comment: Check whether LOAD2.Text has the correct value, try putting a break point and examine the property

Comment: It is literally the text as it is written to both the save file and in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
ServoDir.Checked = LOAD2.Text.ToLower() == "counter clockwise"
```

This will set the Checked property of your CheckBox to true if lowercase trimmed Load2.Text is "counter clockwise", otherwise it will be false.
If you are using strings to set some values try to do lowercase/uppercase comparison and also trim the string so that whitespaces are removed from the start and end of string.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that you should try replace the whole if statement with the above code.

EDIT:
If above code does not work, try to set the IsChecked property to true/false.